# Take a list of functions and compose the list with a value

Tags: haskell, function-composition

I'm currently attempting to do this problem from the ebook, Haskell School of Music:

> Define a function applyAll that, given a list of functions
>   [ f1, f2, ..., fn ] and a value v, returns the result f1 (f2 (...(fn v)...)).
>
> For example:
>   applyAll [simple 2 2, (+3)] 5 ⇒ 20

Currently I have

```
simple       :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer
simple x y z = x * (y + z)

applyAll          :: [(f -> a)] -> a -> a
applyAll [f] v  = foldr (.) v [f]

a = (applyAll [simple 2 2, (+3)] 5)
print a
```

Which gives me the error:

```
Couldn't match type `f' with `a0 -> f'
  `f' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for applyAll :: [f -> a] -> a -> a

Expected type: (f -> a) -> a -> a
  Actual type: (f -> a) -> (a0 -> f) -> a0 -> a
In the first argument of `foldr', namely `(.)'
In the expression: foldr (.) v [f]
```

I'm assuming it has something to do with the type signature, but nothing I've tried so far has yielded results.

Comment: Do you have a question here?

Comment: My question was what am I doing wrong here to get this error.  I apologize if I worded it incorrectly or if it's an improper question to ask, I'm new to the site and not completely familiar with the posting etiquette.  However, jozefg's reply did answer everything I wanted to know about the issue.

Comment: That is good. Just some food for thought for the future. Make sure your "question" always has a question in it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that the type of `.` is `(b->c) -> (a->b) -> a -> c` but our initial value for our fold is not a function. To put this in english, `.` is function composition, but we want function application. This is easily solved however with `($)`.

```
($) f a = f a
```

so

```
applyAll :: [(f -> a)] -> a -> a
applyAll [f] v  = foldr ($) v [f]
```

Next we have a problem with the `[f]` part. All that does is match a single element list which is probably not what you want.

```
applyAll fs v = foldr ($) v fs
```

Now we need to deal with one last part, the type signature. Our function can't take in functions of type `f -> a` because when we connect them we'll feed a function a value of type `a` when it expects an `f`. So the end result is

```
 applyAll :: [a -> a] -> a -> a
 applyAll fs v = foldr ($) v fs
```